# Automatically refresh Drupal node after hook_view

Tags: drupal, cck

I'm trying to show updated results for a CCK Computed Field.

The computation is based on fields in another node, so are not being automatically updated.

So: I'm calling `node_save($node)` in `hook_view`, which does make the adjustment but the results don't show until I refresh the page.

Is there a way to refresh the page automatically, or should I be approaching this from a different angle?

Edit: In response to Henrik's questions, here's more detail:
The `hook_view` and its `node_save` are below, the rest of the code is in a Computed Field in the 'project' content type, summing up values from another node. Without the `node_save`, I have to edit and save the 'project' node to get the result. With it, I just need to refresh the page.

Adding `drupal_goto(drupal_get_destination())` in the `hook_view` gives a 'page not found', rather than the vicious loop I was expecting. Is there another place I could put it?

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
      if($node->type == 'project') {
        project_view($node);
      break;
      }
  }
}

function project_view($node) {
    node_save($node);
    return $node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I updated my answer with some new options, as well as fixing my bone headed first suggestion for the redirection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is only ever going to be computed, you could just add something to your node at load time.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load':
      if($node->type == 'project') {
         $node->content['myfield'] = array('#value' => mymodule_calculate_value(), '#weight' => 4, '#theme' => 'my_theme');  
       }
      break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good alternative, but it's frustrating that I can't work out how to do it directly with the Computed Field.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1:** Given the newly posted code and additional explanations, I have three suggestions that might solve the problem without redirecting:

1. As `project_view()` does not take the node argument by reference, you might want to actually grab its (potentially updated) result in `mymodule_nodeapi` by writing

   ```
   $node = project_view($node);
   ```

   instead of just

   ```
   project_view($node);
   ```
2. If that works, it should also work without the indirection via `project_view()` by just calling `node_save($node)` directly in `mymodule_nodeapi`. (`node_save()` takes the node argument by reference).
3. AFAIK, computed fields basically provide two working modes that you can switch via checkbox on the field configuration form:

   1. Computing the field once on `node_save()`, storing the result in the database, updating only on new save operations.
   2. Not storing the field at all, instead recomputing it every time the node is viewed.

   Have you tried the 'always recompute' option already?

---

**Edit 2:** My original answer was flawed in two ways at once, as it used a completely wrong function to retrieve the current request URI and did not check for recursion (as lazysoundsystem pointed out very courteously ;)

So the following has been updated to an actually tested version of doing the redirection:

> Is there a way to refresh the page
>   automatically

You could try:

```
if (!$_REQUEST['stop_redirect']) {
  drupal_goto(request_uri(), array('stop_redirect' => true));
}
```

This will cause Drupal to send a redirect header to the client, causing a new request of the current page, making sure not to redirect again immediately.